# DEADLOCK Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to develop my first Xamarin App.

I have two classes for webservices:
RestClient: which makes the request and get the json String
Helper Class: which should get the Json String and deserialized it to the Object Type.

I know that the `Wait` Method is not the best option, but I have tried so many different suggested versions but it doesn't work. Every try ended in a Deadlock. Every Thread works in the Background. How can I get my Data back to the UI?

code of my RestClient Class:

```
class RestClient
{

    public static string base_url = @"our Restservice address";
    //  public string completeUrl { get; set; }

    HttpClient client;

    public RestClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress  = new Uri(base_url);
        //client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    }

    public async Task<String> GetData(string endpoint)
    {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Code of my Helper Class

```
public SupplierHelper()
{
}
public async Task<Suppliers> getData()
{
    RestClient restClient = new RestClient();

    string result =  await restClient.GetData("suppliers/13");
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Suppliers>(result);
}
```

Code of my VievModelClass

```
public class AccountViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public static SupplierHelper supHelper;
    public static Suppliers sup;
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Address { set; get; }

    public AccountViewModel()
    {
        loadSupplier().Wait();
    }

    public  async Task loadSupplier()
    {
        supHelper = new SupplierHelper();
        sup =    await supHelper.getData();
    }   
}
```

Comment: probably `Wait()` causes this deadlock. Since you can't make a constructor *async* you think *Wait* can make it work.  No ,change your logic (For ex, you can move that code to an async method of *AccountViewModel* `if(sub==null) await loadSupplier()` ).

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
to know your way arround here (and earn your first badge also ;) ). Also to improve the chances of getting useful answers
please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and also how to create [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Task.Run(loadSupplier).Wait();` will solve your problem.
Your deadlock is caused by async method trying to execute continuation on caller thread, but caller thread is blocked until that async method completes.

Comment: No, this is flat-out wrong - [don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: This is works. So what is wrong? Because somebody wrote a blog post and said I should not? What if I need to? Like legacy synchronous interface that i implementing? Task.Run wrap up you buggy async code so that you can block on it. Surely you'd better not do it in ctor, but that is not the question.

Answer (score 0):

`.Wait()` is worse than "not the best option" - it'll actively cause a circular wait in any environment that has a synchronization context. Read [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for more details.

If you must call this to init the object correctly, you could use an async Factory method or something.

Comment: Provide some solution